# Business Class Internet issues

Tags: networking, router, internet, wireless-router, ipv4

I recently moved from residential internet, to business internet via Comcast.  As I intend to house a website out of my home and need static ip's.

But I also do home stuff as well.

ISP Support will not help me with my router config and am wondering if you can help me with this current problem, I have other problems as well but this one is really vexing.

I have our internal network on 192.168.1.*, gateway 192.168.1.1, both wired and wifi on the same network all fed from my router.

We have personal and server computers throughout the house, and we use switches for local areas and big cable to the main router.  My son cannot see my computer even though he is on the same network.

He is 192.168.1.81
I am 192.168.1.75 both are DHCP.

I can ping him.
He cannot ping me.
Both of us have no trouble accessing the internet.

We have a printer on wifi, on 192.168.1.159.  I can bring it up with a web browser and ping it, he cannot do either.

Our router is CGA4131COM
Hardware Revision: 2.1

Now there is a switch between me and him, and I have ordered another one to replace it, but that will take a few days and I doubt it is the problem.

Is there some setting or protocol in place that might prevent us from communicating?   I have been doing ipv4 for decades and have never seen this before.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your son's network connection set to "private" or "work" and does he have file and printer sharing enabled?

Comment: He has network and printer sharing turned on his windows box.   As far as private and work not sure what that is?

Comment: Someone at work suggested perhaps this is a bad router and has setup a segmented vlan or perhaps the switch has.   Has anyone heard of this before?  How could I check for that?

Comment: I think they actually got rid of "work profile" actually, but you'd set it in the network properties. File and printer sharing settings are presented as a subset to one of these profiles ( https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4043043/windows-10-make-network-public-private )

Comment: Is your computer on Wi-Fi? Is your son's computer on Wi-Fi? If both are on Wi-Fi, are they both associated to the same SSID? Are they both connected to the same band (2.4GHz vs 5GHz)? Do the Wi-Fi settings of your Wi-Fi AP have anything about "client isolation" or something similar? For wireless security, you should be using WPA2 only (AES-CCMP only); make sure you don't have original WPA/TKIP enabled or available in any way; bugs with WPA/TKIP implementations can break multicast/broadcast which breaks ARP, which can breaks the ability for one device to ping another.

Comment: both computers are wired, mine directly into the router, my son's through a network switch (unmanaged) to the router